# ajax php update progress bar value from foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, foreach

I'm trying to update a HTML progress bar using data from a Ajax post request. The numbered value is pulled in from a PHP variable set from a foreach loop based upon email success. I'm struggling to find a way to send the value from PHP to the html progress bar using jQuery and Ajax.

I have a standard ajax request thats working fine and here is my PHP code foreach loop:

```
foreach ($result as $person) { 

        $to = $person->post_title;
        $headers = "From: " . bloginfo( 'name' ) ." <". get_option( 'admin_email' ) .">\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". get_option( 'admin_email' ) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
        $message = $content;

        $send_email = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

        if( $send_email ) {

        $email_count_update++;

        }

       // All emails have been sent
        if( $email_count_update == $email_count ) {

          $response->add( array(
          'data'  =>  'success',
          'supplemental' => array(
            'message' => __( 'Emails sent', 'mup' )
            )
          ));

         $response->send();

        }

    }
```

Any help would great as I've been up all night!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put it in $_SESSION variable and with setInterval in js print the session value and at the end destroy the session variable

Comment: Session gets added at the end when all emails are sent - not when incremented.

Comment: You can add some different session variable and check for that, if is't changing... And unset it at the end off loop with session_unset($_SESSION['other_variable']);

Comment: Problem is that I am getting all the responses at the end - not after 1 email is sent.

Comment: Yes, with $response->send();, but you can when you increment value do something like : $_SESSION['counter'] = $email_count_update;  and create function when you call ajax to do before that function : setInterval( function(){ $('.progress_bar').val(<?php echo $_SESSION['counter']; ?> ); },1000); so it can print the value of the counter in the progress bar value.. It's an idea, not the best solution...

Comment: I get an unexpected token when using: function : setInterval( function(){ $('._progress_bar').val(<?php echo $_SESSION['counter']; ?> ); },1000); what function hook do I attach this to?

Comment: Before you call ajax function ( onClick or something ) you should call function setInterval() ) You should call that function without function: setInterval, i just typed like that ... ( i am on mobile so cant see if its typed ok :-) ) it's like this: setInterval(function(){ // do something here },1000);

Answer (score -1):

In email send function add setting $_SESSION value which will hold current $email_count_update value. To avoid conflicts when user calls multiple requests send unique value from JS in AJAX requst to PHP. Let it be $_GET['request_unique'].

In your code add:

```php
if( $send_email ) {
    $email_count_update++;
    $SESSION['email_counter' . $_GET['request_unique']] = $email_count_update;
}
```

Create separate action in PHP (let it respond to url `/counter`) which called with $_GET['request_unique'] will return this value:

```php
$response->add(
    array('email_count_update' => $SESSION['email_counter' . $_GET['request_unique']])
)->send();
```

In Javascript, after making request to sending action check this PHP session value every second:

```js
setInterval(function(){
   //make AJAX request to /counter?request_unique=XXX
   //get email_count_update from response and update progressbar
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This is confusing me a little - I'm getting the values back from the ajax request but only at the end state - when all emails are sent. How can I send a session at each send interval?? - When I send via $response it ends the process rather than carrying on through the foreach

Comment: As I said, you need to create separate action (php file, action in controller) which will return $_SESSION value. In setInterval call this helper action, not the main which sends emails.